# converting dates to quarters while displaying the correct fiscal year

Tags: microsoft-excel

My current problem is that the below formula is displaying `Q1 2014`.  I need it to display `Q1 2015`, as our fiscal year begins Dec 1st.  All other months are displaying correctly.

Cell A1 is: `12/1/2014  3:16:57 PM`

Formula is

```
    =CHOOSE(INT(MOD(MONTH(A1)-12,12)/3)+1,"Q1 ","Q2 ","Q3 ","Q4 ")&YEAR(A1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track but it may be better to push the current date ahead one month rather than subtract 12.

[image: Quarterlies]

The formula in B1 is,

`="Q"&INT((MONTH(EOMONTH(A1,0)+1)-1)/3)+1&CHAR(32)&YEAR(EOMONTH(A1,0)+1)`

Comment: As per my similar answer elsewhere you can simply offset the date by 31 days, e.g. use `YEAR(A1+31)`